# AzureSearch edgeNGram search matching too many documents

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, n-gram

I'm trying to implement a prefix search using a field analyzed with an edge ngram analyzer.
However, whenever I do a search, it returns similar matches, but that do not contain the searched term.

The following query

```
POST /indexes/resources/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30

{
"queryType": "full",
"searchMode": "all",
"search": "short_text_prefix:7024032"
}
```

Returns

```
{
"@odata.context": ".../indexes('resources')/$metadata#docs(*)",
"@search.nextPageParameters": {
    "queryType": "full",
    "searchMode": "all",
    "search": "short_text_prefix:7024032",
    "skip": 50
},
"value": [
    {
    "@search.score": 4.669537,
    "short_text_prefix": "7024032   "
    },
    {
    "@search.score": 4.6333756,
    "short_text_prefix": "7024030   "
    },
    {
    "@search.score": 4.6333756,
    "short_text_prefix": "7024034   "
    },
    {
    "@search.score": 4.6333756,
    "short_text_prefix": "7024031   "
    },
    {
    "@search.score": 4.6319494,
    "short_text_prefix": "7024033   "
    },
    ... omitted for brevity ...
],
"@odata.nextLink": ".../indexes('resources')/docs/search.post.search?api-version=2020-06-30"
}
```

Which includes a bunch of documents which almost match my term. And the "correct" document with the highest score on top.

The custom analyzer tokenizes "7024032   " like this

```
"@odata.context": "/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2020_06_30.AnalyzeResult",
"tokens": [
    {
    "token": "7",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "70",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "702",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "7024",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "70240",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "702403",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "7024032",
    "startOffset": 0,
    "endOffset": 7,
    "position": 0
    }
]
}
```

How do I exclude the documents which did not match the term exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

I had created the field with the "analyzer" property referring to my custom analyzer ("edge_nGram_analyzer"). Setting this field means the string are tokenized both on indexing and when searching. So searching for "7024032" meant I was searching for all tokens, split according to the egde n-gram analyzer: "7", "70", "702", "7024", "7024032", "70240", "702403", "7024032"

The indexAnalyzer and searchAnalyzer properties can instead be used, to handle index-tokenizing separately from search-tokenizing. When I used them separately:

```
{ "indexAnalyzer": "edge_nGram_analyzer", "searchAnalyzer": "whitespace" }
```

everything worked as expected.

Comment: Good explanation of the difference between the different field properties for analyzer.  Very helpful.  I was struggling with the difference between AnalyzerName, SearchAnalyzerName, and IndexAnalyzerName.

Answer (score 0):

Ngram is not the right way in this case as the prefix '702403' appears in all those documents. You can use it if you specify the minimum length to be the length of the term you're searching for.

Here's an example:

token length: 3

sample content:

234

1234

2345

3456

001234

99234345

searching for '234'

it would return items 1 (234), 2 (1234), 3 (2345), 4 (001234) and 5 (99234345)

Another option, if you're 100% the content is stored in the way you presented, you could use regular expression to retrieve the way you want:

/.*7024032\s+/

[image]

Comment: Not sure I follow. "7024032" (my search term) is only present in one of the documents. The top one in the results.

And my search term is "short_text_prefix:7024032". Which I would guess means it tries to find the token "7024032" in the token list "7", "70", "702", "7024", "7024032", "70240", "702403", "7024032". 

The second document would contain "7", "70", "702", "7024", "7024032", "70240", "702403", "7024030" (the last token differs) and should not match the query is my understanding.

I don't believe regex matching is effiecient enough for our data volume.

Comment: To be clear I'm trying to implement efficient prefix matching on the field short_text_prefix

Comment: about your first comment, this is exactly the opposite. The sub tokens also exists in other documents, this is why they are being retrieved. The document you're trying to retrieve contains all the tokens, this is why it's retrieved first (or in search terms, is more relevant).

Comment: See my own answer. Separating indexAnalyzer and searchAnalyzer was the way to go.

The full 7024032-token did not exist in all the documents. But when searching it was split into ngrams, which matched all documents containing even the same first character.